# FirefoxCP Isolated Web Content CPU overdrive

Tags: support

Just recently, MathOverflow has started to cause Firefox to use massive CPU resources, at least on my machine. In particular, I'm on a Macbook Pro 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9 running Ventura 13.4.1 and Firefox 116.0.2. Some MathOverflow posts cause "FirefoxCP Isolated Web Content" to consume 100% of CPU time, as reported by the Activity Monitor. Is this something I can do something about, or is there something amiss with the MathOverflow software/interface?

Comment: I wonder whether you might have bigger chance of getting some useful response on [su] or [apple.se] rather then here.
Two questions which seem relatively natural: Does this happen on other Stack Exchange sites, too? Does this happen only on pages with MathJax?

Comment: What posts? Posts with several MathJax-heavy answers (such as this one: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330683/dividing-a-cake-between-n-1-n-or-n1-guests/452721) have always required lots of CPU to finish rendering of all the MathJax snippets.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, that post does cause the problem, so it probably is something to do with MathJax. Thanks for your help. I do still find it odd that even after the MathJax rendering is complete, the CPU is still at 100% usage for a while.

Comment: I have at least mentioned this in the chatrooms for [Super User](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118/2023/8/22) and [Ask Different](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/38/2023/8/22) - you can see for yourself what response was there so far. (We'll see whether somebody will add some useful advice there.) If nothing else, one user mentions the same behavior under Windows - so this doesn't seem to be specific to Mac.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinSleziak!

Comment: Conforming that FF on linux does the same - 100% CPU usage when that example tab is displayed, but normally idle when any other tab is selected.   Curiiously, FF's own task manager at `about:performance`   might not even show a line for that tab, and when it did was only displaying "power impact: medium`